# Reading NULL values with MFCs RFX (Record Field Exchange)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mfc, null, odbc, recordset

I'm using RFX ([Record Field Exchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8staww2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) to move data from a ODBC data source to my Recordset object. Numbers are moved with [RFX_Int](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s14b12eb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (within `DoFieldExchange`) and apparently the database NULL (not a value) is mapped to a pseudo null value `AFX_RFX_INT_PSEUDO_NULL`. Unfortunately this sentinel value is defined as `0x7ee4` or 32484 in decimal. This value lies in the middle of the possible `int` number range and is a valid number to my application!

Following code part gives a wrong result with records containing the (valid) value 32484 in `mainarticle`.

```cpp
std::vector<Article> getArticles() {
    std::vector<Article> res;
    CArticleRecordset tmp(&con.GetConnectedDB());
    tmp.Open();
    while (!tmp.IsEOF()) {
        if (tmp.m_article.mainarticle == AFX_RFX_INT_PSEUDO_NULL)
            tmp.m_article.mainarticle = 0;
        res.push_back(tmp.m_article);
        tmp.MoveNext();
    }
    return res;
}
```

How could I solve this?

The pseudo null values are defined in `afxdb_.h` (Visual Studio 2010):

```cpp
#define AFX_RFX_SHORT_PSEUDO_NULL (0x7EE4)
#define AFX_RFX_INT_PSEUDO_NULL (0x7EE4)
#define AFX_RFX_LONG_PSEUDO_NULL (0x4a4d4120L)
#define AFX_RFX_BIGINT_PSEUDO_NULL (0x4a4d4120L)
#define AFX_RFX_BYTE_PSEUDO_NULL 255
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RFX_Int` is poorly named, it was meant to be used with short integers. Use `RFX_Long` instead.

Comment: [RFX_Int](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s14b12eb(v=vs.80).aspx) expects `int&` as third parameter and `RFX_Long` expects `&LONG`, but with a temporary `LONG` variable within `DoDataExchange` and (after calling `RFX_Long`) assigning it to `mainarticle`, I can live with your suggestion. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @ChristianAmmer, in Microsoft land `int` and `long` are identical. And `LONG` is typedefed to `long` in `WinNT.h`. You shouldn't need the temporary.